# org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed: Script7.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class

Tags: eclipse, exception, selenium, groovy, soapui

I am currently receiving this error when trying to run a soapui file:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException:
startup failed: Script7.groovy: 1: unable to resolve class com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate @ line 1, column 1.     
  import com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate
                             ^
org.codehaus.groovy.syntax.SyntaxException: unable to resolve class com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate @ line 1, column 1.
 at org.codehaus.groovy.ast.ClassCodeVisitorSupport.addError(ClassCodeVisitorSupport.java:148)  
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.visitClass(ResolveVisitor.java:1206)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.ResolveVisitor.startResolving(ResolveVisitor.java:148)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit$6.call(CompilationUnit.java:585)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.applyToSourceUnits(CompilationUnit.java:832)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.doPhaseOperation(CompilationUnit.java:519)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.processPhaseOperations(CompilationUnit.java:495)
 at org.codehaus.groovy.control.CompilationUnit.compile(CompilationUnit.java:472)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.parseClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:292)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parseClass(GroovyShell.java:727)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:739)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:766)
 at groovy.lang.GroovyShell.parse(GroovyShell.java:757)
 at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.compile(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:141)
 at com.eviware.soapui.support.scripting.groovy.SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.run(SoapUIGroovyScriptEngine.java:90)
 at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.teststeps.WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.run(WsdlGroovyScriptTestStep.java:148)
 at com.eviware.soapui.impl.wsdl.panels.teststeps.GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel$RunAction$1.run(GroovyScriptStepDesktopPanel.java:274)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
 at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:619)
 1 error
```

soapUI code:

```
import com.company.ui.test.SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate

def env = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("env")
def baseUrl = testRunner.testCase.testSuite.project.getPropertyValue("baseUrl")

log.info("The baseurl is "+baseUrl)
log.info("The env under test is "+env)

SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate testStep = new SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate();
testStep.init(baseUrl);
testStep.execute(null);
```

eclipse code:

```
package com.company.ui.test;

import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;

import com.eviware.soapui.model.support.AbstractSubmitContext;
import com.eviware.soapui.model.testsuite.TestRunner;

public class SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate extends BaseSelenium{
   public static void main(final String[] args){
      final SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate ico = new SoapUI_T11001_StockConsSecurityCurBusiDate();
      try{
         ico.init("https://avncedevn1.nam.nsroot.net:17620/", false);
      }catch(Exception e){
         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
         e.printStackTrace();
      }
      ico.execute(null);
   }
        //...code....
}
```

how do I solve this error ? I'm not sure what is causing the error.

Comment: @tim_yates 
I've included the .jar for the code I needed to run. added it into the soapui > bin >ext folder and now it works. 
thanks for your previous pointer

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Do you have the grail and groovy plugin installed? If so try uninstalling this plugin. I had the same error message and uninstalling the plugin, restart IDE worked for me.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your suggestion.
I actually created a new clean project in soapui and it worked for me.

Comment: it helped me today, in 2021

Comment: didn't help at all , uninstalling groovy plugin made android studio not functionable!

Comment: we had to reinstall android stuido when uninstalling this plugin..!! wrong thing to do

Comment: please do not try this answer

Comment: This is not a good answer.

Answer (score 40):

This work for me:
Press Ctr+Alt+Shift+s
or:
From File menu -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> JDK location Drop down menu choose:
Embeded JDK c:....\jre
Then ok.

[image]

Comment: or go to settings and then change JDK to embedded , if jdk settings are not displaying in project structure !

Comment: This answer worked like a charm! Thank you.

Comment: this answer works for me. I encountered this when I use java 16, and changing to embedded jdk (11) solved the quesiton.

Comment: Now it's in Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Gradle JDK" dropdown (select "Embedded JDK version 11")

Comment: JDK location is disabled.

Answer (score 30):

If you using android studio and got this error then I solved it changing the Gradle version of the project to the newest version 6.2.1 on the project structure options.

[image: Image Android Studio]

Comment: Best working solution! I Just chose the latest gradle and i can finally access design tab

Comment: If your gradle version is correct and still have the problem, select SDK Location and set your  jdk location to embedded jdk

Comment: Thank you @AlbinBaby Selecting embedded jdk did the trick, again, Thank you for saving my day.

Comment: Thank you increased gradle version to 7.2

Answer (score 12):

One of the possible reasons is that the jdk version is too *high*. For example, using jdk 16 to build the source code of Apache Kafka throws this error. Using jdk 11 is fine.

Answer (score 7):

I'm Using Android Studio - Arctic Fox and this worked for me

Go To File menu -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> Gradle Setting

[image]

Then check the "Download external annotations for dependencies" button and select JDK location from the drop down menu and choose: Android Default Jdk Vesion.

Click on Ok.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

build.gradle file in change classpath

```
dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.1"
       
    }
```

gradel-wrapper.properties

```
 distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.0.2-bin.zip
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Open Gradle Settings

   [image]
2. Change Gradle JDK And Set 11 Under Gradle Projects

   [image]
3. Now rebuild

Comment: isso resolveu para mim

Answer (score 3):

I changed my Java version from `20.0.1` to `17.0.1`. This is because Java version between 8 and 19 is required to execute my project with `gradle` `7.5.` I found the issue was that `Java 20` version is not yet supported to execute `gradle 7.5`.

That's all how I fixed this error.

Answer (score 2):

If you wanted to make a new project on Android Studio after first install, probably you write your application name including (') sign as called apostrophe.

For Example, I tried to set a name as: "Henry's Game" but apostrophe caused Android Studio to not load because of this mistake:

```
Caused by: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
```

So, just change your application's name, and simply use Latin alphabet languages such as English.

To fix: Go to your Android Project Tree and find Gradle Scripts > settings.gradle > change the name:

```
rootProject.name='Henry Game'
include ':app'
```

Answer (score 1):

With Eclipse Juno (Kepler Release) Build id: 20121114-2344, I found similar problem:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.multiplecompilationerrorsexception startup failed unable to resolve class Chart
```

The class Chart is my container class for some utilities for charting.

I tried outside of Eclipse, with Groovy 2.0 Console the same code segment works fine. After scratching my head for about 3 hours, I resolved it by adding the following

```
import excel.Chart
```

in the invoking class with main() that has "`new Chart()`" thus getting the complaints, once added, the error is gone. Even more weird, after passing the error, I remove that import, there is still no more complaints! (All my scripts/classes are under the same package `excel`, I suppose such import statement is not needed.)

One of the symptom of the complaints is that there was not Chart.class generated in the output bin folder. Once the complaints gone, Chart.class appeared there.

I guess that it might be a bug of Eclipse/Groovy plugin (I use Groovy Plugin for Juno).

Hope my understanding is correct, and it helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution for me was change the gradle version and the Gradle JDK:

File > Project Structure > Project

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/It6OS.png)

File > Project Structure > SDK Location

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Im1jg.png)

Answer (score 0):

Go to Files and click Invalidate caches/ Restart . Android studio will clear the cached and it will be restarted without any error.

Hope this answer helps you :)

Answer (score 0):

For this problem, you might also encounter **package** naming **from gsp** as I did. In the ***build/gsptmp*** folder, **Grails 4.x.x**  creates temporary gsp files to link the classes that they refer to. Due to the change of a package name it was failing to do so in my case. Try with command `grails war --stacktrace` during war build!

Previously, it was `<%@ page import="bv.BankReconciliationController" %>`
but the folder **bv** was renamed to **factoring**.
So, the solve was to change the import to
`<%@ page import="factoring.BankReconciliationController" %>` and it worked :)

Answer (score 0):

I have also faced the same and tried all of the solution here and other places as well, at last i deleted my .gradle and gradle both folder and caches of android studio and open the studio again and rebuild the project, it's works after that fine and used the latest gradle version and previously it was picking up the older version and causing issues.

Answer (score 0):

for me , solution is to upgrade the gradle to latest version , and remove the .idea file , and invalidate caches and restart android studio.

Answer (score 0):

When starting a project make sure to select SDK version 11 or later. It will default to a minimum SDK but you have to scroll down to a later version for it to work. Then the project should load and build.

Answer (score 0):

For me, I just delete the .grade file under program files(C:\Users\username\ .gradle) in windows and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

This work for me:
From File menu -> Project Structure -> SDK Location -> klik Gradle Setting for show hide menu, Gradle JDK choose:

- Embeded JDK c:....\jre
  Then ok.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this in just three steps:

1. Press Ctr+Alt+Shift+s after that upgrade gradel version to the latest one
2. Check the java version in your system[image]
3. configure gradle jdk to that version, you can find gradle JDK in
   --> ( Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Gradle -> "Gradle JDK" )